# Checking membership in DFA with fixed length using AC1 circuit?

Tags: complexity-theory, finite-automata, decision-problem, circuits

I'm supposed to find circuits , which can solve the question of membership in a regular language A with fixed length. The depth is limited by O(log(n)) and the size by O(n).  Divide and Conquer should be the way to go, but I always exceed the max size. Would really appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ by a balanced binary tree with $n$ leaves, and label each internal node $v$ by the interval $I_v$ consisting of the leaves below $v$. For each $v$ we will calculate the a two-place relation $R_v(s,t)$ which checks whether $I_v$ causes the automaton to move from $s$ to $t$. If $a,b$ are the two children of $v$, then
$$
R_v(s,t) = \bigvee_u (R_a(s,u) \land R_b(u,t)).
$$
For a leaf $f$, $R_f(s,t) = [\delta(s,x_f) = t]$, where $x_f$ is the $f$th input, and $\delta$ is the transition function. If $r$ is the root of the tree then the final answer is
$$
\bigvee_{q \in F} R_r(q_0,q),
$$
where $q_0$ is the initial state and $F$ is the set of accepting states.

Each node of the tree uses $O(1)$ gates. Since the tree has $O(n)$ nodes, the circuit has size $O(n)$. It's also not difficult to check that it has depth $O(\log n)$. Moreover, the fan-in of each gate is constant (since the number of states is constant), and so this circuit is actually in $\mathsf{NC}^1$.

Note also that the construction works directly for NFAs.

Comment: Do I get that right, you're basically checking in every step, whether the input is the set of valid elements , and split it up?

Comment: I don't quite get what s and t are.  Are these states in the DFA ?

Comment: I'm just implementing what you suggested - divide and conquer. I'm sure you can figure out the rest from context. It's your exercise, after all.